Execute different stages of a `CompletableFuture` on different `ExecutorService`s
What I am  trying to achieve:
I want to create a CompletableFuture that runs on an ExecutorService, then add a stage to it that executes in a different ExecutorService.
What I have tried:
try (ExecutorService benchRunner = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1);
     ExecutorService resultHandler = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
    for (Algorithm algorithm : Algorithm.values()) {
        for (Distribution distribution : Distribution.values()) {
            for (Integer arraySize : List.of(30, 60, 90, 300, 600, 900, 3000, 6000, 9000)) {
                SortingBenchmark.Config config = new SortingBenchmark.Config(arraySize, algorithm, distribution);

                CompletableFuture<Benchmark> benchmarkTask = new CompletableFuture<>();
                benchmarkTask.completeAsync(new SortingBenchmark(config), benchRunner);
                benchmarkTask.whenCompleteAsync((b, t) -> {
                    if (t != null) {
                        System.err.println("Failed on: " + config);
                        return;
                    }

                    System.out.println("Finished: " + config);
                }, resultHandler);
            }
        }
    }
}

My understanding is that whenCompleteAsync should execute on resultHandler after new SortingBenchmark(config) executes on benchRunner. However, when I run this, the code in the whenCompleteAsync section never runs; the completeAsync section however runs just fine (I can tell because 7 of my cores are pinned to 100% usage and I see stdout output).
If I add a join call to benchmarkTask, the code in whenCompleteAsync starts to run, but this "solution" ends up (naturally) causing the whole section to become single threaded.
Am I misunderstanding how whenCompleteAsync works? How do I go about achieving what I want?
Thanks,

Assuming SortingBenchmark#get() takes longer to execute than it takes to schedule all the tasks (i.e., than it takes for your three for loops to execute), then I suspect the problem is that resultHandler.close() is being invoked too soon (by the try-with-resources statement). The ExecutorService#close() method "initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted". So, when whenCompleteAsync goes to schedule its action, it can't because the given thread pool rejects the task due to having been shutdown.

You are correct, I realized later that the try-with-resources does enforce an ordering on how close methods are called.

Yeah, I believe flipping the order you define your executors will solve the problem, since then benchRunner will be closed first, and the call to close() won't return until all previously submitted tasks complete. And that should mean all tasks will be submitted to resultHandler before it has its own close() method invoked.

If that's the solution you used, or even some other solution, consider adding an answer to your own question.

Will do, thanks.

Credit to slaw,
The problem is that the try-with-resources statement enforces reverse-ordering on the order in which close is called on the resources; i.e., resources initiated last are closed first.
In the above example, this causes resultHandler to be closed before the tasks submitted to benchRunner can finish.
Reversing the order in which the resources are initialized fixes the issue.
